# Why is my stored procedure returning 0?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the sum of the `pointsEarned` column and the sum of the `pointsPossible` column. I want to turn this into a percentage. My problem is that my SP always returns 0, even when there are rows with the given `enrollmentId` that have values for the previous columns.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPercentage 
    @enrollmentId int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pointsEarned int;
    DECLARE @pointsPossible int;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        @pointsEarned = CAST(SUM(pointsEarned) OVER() AS decimal), 
        @pointsPossible = CAST(SUM(pointsPossible) OVER() AS decimal)
    FROM 
        Assignments
    WHERE 
        enrollmentId = @enrollmentId

    RETURN @pointsEarned / @pointsPossible
END
GO
```

This is the database table:

[image]

I execute the stored procedure and passed in the `enrollmentId` of 69 and it still returns 0.

Comment: I would get rid of the RETURN and replace it with a SELECT

Comment: show your `exec` script

Comment: Why would you get rid of the return and replace with a `select`? It doesn't solve the problem and completely changes the usage of the SP.

Comment: What result do you expect to get in your example?

Answer (score 2):

Integer division with denominator (`pointsPossible`) greater than numerator (`pointsEarned`) returns zero.

Write as (revised):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPercentage 
    @enrollmentId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        Percent = case when sum(pointsPossible) > 0 then (1.0 * sum(pointsEarned)) / sum(pointsPossible) else 0 end
    FROM 
        Assignments
    WHERE 
        enrollmentId = @enrollmentId
    GROUP BY
        enrollmentId 
END
GO
```

As @ Nick.McDermaid points out, since this procedure return a scalar value, it might be more appropriate to define it as a function rather than a store procedure.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use simple `SUM` without `OVER`.
2. `RETURN` can return only `int`. Integer division will always return 0 if your percentage is less than 100%, so multiply by 100 to return whole percents instead of ratio.
3. Check that you are not dividing by zero.

**Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPercentage 
    @enrollmentId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @pointsEarned int;
    DECLARE @pointsPossible int;

    SELECT 
        @pointsEarned = SUM(pointsEarned),
        @pointsPossible = SUM(pointsPossible)
    FROM 
        Assignments
    WHERE 
        enrollmentId = @enrollmentId
    ;

    RETURN 
        CASE WHEN @pointsPossible <> 0
        THEN 100 * @pointsEarned / @pointsPossible
        ELSE 0 END;

END
GO
```

Comment: @MitchWheat, I think I know what `SUM() OVER()` does. If I understood this question correctly, OP needs a plain sum (one number in one row), not the sum in multiple rows.

Comment: you mean like the answer I posted ? But good point about RETURN can only return an int.

Comment: @MitchWheat, yes, your answer and mine are very similar. You decided to `SELECT` the result as a result set, which can hold non-integer value (`decimal` or `float`). I left original approach which `RETURNs` integer value.  BTW, there is no need for `GROUP BY`, because of filter in `WHERE`.

Comment: RE: GROUP BY": yes, I know. It's there out of habit.